# A short title for a collection that contains items related to software features and requirements

Tags: single-word-requests, titles

I have a list of items that contain terms related to software subsystems and requirements. Here is my list:

- Archiving
- Automation
- Collaboration
- Customization
- Performance
- Publication
- Regulatory Compliance
- Reliability
- Security
- Standards Compliance
- User Interface

I need to give the list itself a title. The list is going to be used within a project management software to allow categorization of feature requests. More than one item can be selected. A colleague of mine suggested the title *Tags* (seems like a IDGAF answer) another suggested *Modality*. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure this question will help the wider internet. Sorry, Nick, I think you request is too localised for Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply 'categories'?  Or... classes?

Comment: Since you state the purpose is to allow categorization, categories makes sense to me. Since it's for features, maybe you want to qualify and call them "feature categories."